# Помощь с областью видимости и замыканиями в python

Tags: python-3.x, функции, замыкания

У меня есть задание:

> Допишите функцию make_divider_of() так, чтобы на её основе можно было
> создавать производные функции, делящие переданный аргумент на
> определённое число. Делитель должен передаваться при создании
> производной функции. Например, функция div2(), приведённая в коде,
> будет делить любой переданный в неё числовой аргумент на 2 и
> возвращать результат.

Прилагаю код:

```
def make_divider_of(divider):
    def division_operation(divisible):
    
    # Ваш код здесь
```

И примеры того, что должно получиться:

```
div2 = make_divider_of(2)
print(div2(10))  # Такой вызов должен вернуть 10/2, то есть 5.0

div5 = make_divider_of(5)
print(div5(20))  # Такой вызов должен вернуть 4.0 

print(div5(div2(20)))  # Такой вызов должен вернуть 2.0
```

**Вопрос:** я не совсем понимаю, как работает замыкание конкретно в этом случае. Я пытался сделать что-то вроде:

```
def make_divider_of(divider):
    def division_operation(divisible):
        return divisible / divider
```

И наоборот, менял местами: divider/divisible, но такое ощущение, что я просто перебираю варианты по пальцам и ни к чему не иду. Прошу, пожалуйста, разжевать подробнее, что должно произойти в коде для получения результата и как оно работает. Спасибо!

Comment: `return division_operation` в конец make_divider_of

Comment: Ведь у вас вышла конкретная ошибка, надо было её привести в вопросе. И подумать - почему она вышла, чего не хватает. Питон даёт вам все подсказки, зря вы его не слушаете. А ответ в предыдущем комментарии - именно этого не хватает, ваша головная функция просто ничего не возвращает (возвращает `None`), а нужно возвращать внутреннюю функцию.

Answer (score 2):

```
def make_divider_of(divider):
    def division_operation(divisible):
        return (divisible / divider)
    return division_operation
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Скобки только в return лишние